Pivot Table - filter, but only based on one Column
I have a data set with clients, values, and many years.
I'm trying to compare say 2020 with 2022, but only where the 2022 values are greater than 10,000:
Client  Value      Year
A       $1,000     2020
A       $1,000     2021
A       $9,000     2022
B       $4,000     2020
B       $4,000     2021
B       $20,000    2022
C       $1,000     2020
C       $1,000     2021
C       $1,000     2022

My Pivot Table is simple,

but if I do a VALUE filter where VALUE > 10,000 - it keeps client A (because the total of Client A > 10,000):

How can I add a filter that checks if the value in 2022 is over 10,000?
(Note, I can't just add a column to my original data table and use that as a helper. In reality, I'm pulling from a database/OLAP, so am trying to solve this "within" the PivotTable itself).
Edit: My dataset is a ridiculous amount of rows, so unfortunately slicing by picking individual values won't work.
Edit2: I've also tried filtering the years to only keep 2022, add a >=10000 value filter, which then returns only Customer B...but then when I remove the Year filter, it shows up with Customer A again.

u can try: =IF('2022' > 10000, '2022', 0) ?

The only thing I can think of is using a slicer, but it would involve quite a bit of manipulation and would be cumbersome on a large data set...

@cybernetic.nomad - I thought of that too, but my dataset is a ton of rows, so doing that manually (or even VBA) won't really be practical :/

What about inserting a slicer for the data in the column, then filter that way. I know this is additional steps but can work.

There's an option, but it's not very dynamic and would need to be updated if the underlying dataset is updated.
Set up the PivotTable however you need, but only keep the year you want to filter, so 2022 in this case:

Then, apply the value filter to show only those values over 10,000:

In reality, you will have more than a single customer, however what you can do is copy all customers left to a list, and save that list somewhere.
Then remove your value filters, and get back to the original dataset, and add in the additional years you want/need to compare.
THEN -> Add a filter to the PivotTable for the Client Names.  Using VBA, or manually, then only select those clients you found from above.
(Posting here, as I'm thinking through this and this would be an option. I can post some VBA script later to show how to apply it. It's basically taking the range of names I saved, putting those in a list, and then adding that list to the Filter on the Pivot Table for Client Names. Then drag the Client from "Filters" to "Rows")

Using Advanced Criteria

Enter you criteria somewhere (L13:L14 in the example)
select the cell to the right of 'Grand Total' in your pivot table (K5 in the example)
Click on 'Advanced Filter' from the Data tab
Pivot table range is automatically selected as the list range
Set the criteria range

When you refresh to update the pivot table after changes in the underlying dataset, the filter is not automatically applied, so:

select the cell to the right of 'Grand Total' in your pivot table (K5 in the example)
The criteria range will be prefilled
Click 'Ok' - table will be updated to reflect the filter


I haven't tested it extensively, would like to know whether it works with your dataset.

This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac).

Pivot the table using power query
Save and load back to the Excel worksheet
When you do this, you will see separate filters for the different years that you can apply

To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Client", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}, {"Year", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", 
        {{"Year", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Year", type text}}, "en-US")[Year]), "Year", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"

Data

Pivot from Power Query

Apply Filter

If you require the Grand Totals

The Row Grand totals column can be added within the query
The Column Grand Totals row can be added to the table itself on the worksheet. That way it will not be included in the filter

eg:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Client", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}, {"Year", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", 
        {{"Year", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", 
            {{"Year", type text}}, "en-US")[Year]), "Year", "Value", List.Sum),
    #"Add Row Totals" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Grand Total", each 
        List.Sum(List.RemoveFirstN(Record.FieldValues(_),1)), Int64.Type)
in
    #"Add Row Totals"




You can make a side table with your filtering criteria (orange in the screenshot below). The trick is to make sure that it lines up with your Pivot Table.
When you filter that side table, it will hide the entire row on the sheet.

